# DataTables row moving behind bootstrap modal using RowReorder

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, z-order

I´m using DataTables on a Bootstrap modal window, and when I implement the RowReorder Extension works fine, except that the row following the mouse pointer occurs behind the modal. Is there a way to set that up so I can see the row moving in front of the screen over the modal window? Something like z-order or so? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you share some HTML/CSS and some javacript ?

Comment: reproduce the issue in fiddle and better share screen shot

Comment: Yes, you should really provide an example. See this -> **http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask** and **http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve** you get a far better chance for an useful answer, and good questions are upvoted more = more rep to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a bootstrap `.modal` have `z-index: 1050` and the `.modal-backdrop` a `z-index: 1040`. So all you have to do is to ensure the `z-index` for the RowReorder floating element has a higher rank :

```css
table.dt-rowReorder-float {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/L82z0jgj/**